# aspectjweaver/javaagent in a sbt-assembly fatjar

Tags: java, scala, sbt, aspectj, sbt-assembly

I have a library that requires me to specify a javaagent using the aspectjweaver jar.
eg.

```
java -jar  -javaagent:/some/location/aspectjweaver-1.8.2.jar myFatJar.jar
```

This works fine. However, the environment that my fatjar will be running on does not have aspectjweaver-1.8.2.jar and I can't put it there (getting a more configurable environment may be a route I go down later).

Is there a way, preferably using sbt-assembly, to package up aspectjweaver into my fatjar, and run it that way? If it matters, my application is a Spray one using Scala, built using sbt.

Constraints

- Can't have a separate jar
- Can specify an arbitrary java command
- Have complete control of the build process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have, as you say, complete control over the build process, why don't you use compile-time weaving instead of load-time weaving? Then you just package the AspectJ runtime library *aspectjrt.jar* into your fat jar and are done with the problem. You even avoid the overhead of runtime weaving on application start-up.

The only reason I can think of which makes this approach problematic is that you need to weave joinpoints outside the control of your build process.

---

**Update 2024-03-19:** If you are running your applications as **executable JARs on JRE 9+** (Spring Boot ones or other types), probably [Agent Embedder Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/agent-embedder-maven-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file) is what you want.

It enables you to embed a java agent in your executable JAR and have it started automatically using the [`Launcher-Agent-Class` JVM mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Unique features added by this plugin and unavailable via the original JVM mechanism: You can

- embed and run **multiple agents** (the JVM supports only one out of the box),
- pass an **option string** to each agent, just like from the JVM command line.

Spoiler: I am the author of the plugin and also happen to be the current maintainer of AspectJ.

P.S.: In the case of the AspectJ weaver, as the JVM starts the agent very early, weaving will be active without extra Spring configuration and it should work for all classloaders - no more `ClassLoader [...] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method` errors as seen when hot-attaching the weaver via `spring-instrument.jar`.